# What is concordance probability?

Tags: classification

In one of my questions:

[How to measure test set error with logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79641/how-to-measure-test-set-error-with-logistic-regression)

One of the answers mentioned "concordance probability" or c-index. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the term and there seems to be no Wikipedia page and Google turns up nothing. It's my understanding that it relates to classification.

Comment: You can search this site for c-index and likely find links to what you need.

Comment: @DLDahly is correct: you can find many answers by searching [c-index concordance](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=c-index+concordance), for instance.